# 複数のxibファイルを一括で管理するカスタムクラスを作成したが、、

Tags: ios, swift

こんにちは、一日中ハマっていたので質問させて下さい・・！

TableViewに返すCustomViewCellを作成しています。

**・やりたいこと**
大本のTableViewから、各xibファイルをレンダリングし、
そこでのデータを取ってきた後、それを元に処理するというのを実装しようとしたところ、
躓いてしまいました。

**・状況**
nibファイルを複数作成しており、そのTableViewのrowに応じて　nibファイルをレンダリングしようとしております。
nibファイルには、cellにTextFieldクラスの物や、　UIPickerViewクラスのもの、　ボタンしかないものの３種類です。

以下のUITableViewCellを継承したCustomAddTrainingクラスは、複数のnibファイルに使用できるように、一つのファイルにまとめてあります。
もちろん各nibファイルにはこのCustomAddTrainingに設定してあります。
それが以下のソースです。

**・問題点**
現在の問題は、
myPicker :UIPickerView!と　decideButton: UIButton!がnilと判定されることです。
UITextField!はnilではなく、問題なく動いているのですが、この２つがどうしてもnilとなってしまいます。

（当たり前ですが）ファイルを１つにまとめずに作れば問題なく動くのですが、
UITableViewCellを継承した一つのファイルにまとめると、宣言下のにも関わらず認識されません。

なぜなんでしょうか？ご教授願います！

```
import UIKit

class CustomAddTraining: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

let category = ["Front", "Back", "Abnominal", "Leg", "Hip"]

@IBOutlet weak var done: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var decideButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var myTextField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var myPicker: UIPickerView!



override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    if myTextField != nil {
        myTextField.delegate = self
        myTextField.borderStyle = .RoundedRect
    }

    if myPicker.delegate != nil {
        myPicker.delegate = self
    }
    if myPicker.dataSource  != nil {
        myPicker.dataSource = self
    }

    decideButton?.hidden = true
}


override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state

}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    decideButton.hidden = false
}

@IBAction func decideAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    textFieldShouldReturn(myTextField)
}

func textFieldShouldEndEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    decideButton.hidden = true
    return true
}
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    myTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}

//pickerに表示する列数を返すデータ・ソースメソッド
func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int{
    return 1
}

//行数を返す
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int{
    return category.count

}
//表示するデータを返す
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return category[row]
}
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    print(category[row])
}


}
```

Comment: Harawoさんありがとうございます。

Comment: > nibファイルには、cellにTextFieldクラスの物や、　UIPickerViewクラスのもの、　ボタンしかないものの３種類です。

> 現在の問題は、
myPicker :UIPickerView!と　decideButton: UIButton!がnilと判定されることです。

「ボタンしかない」 nib ファイルがあるということは、少なくとも `myPicker` が `nil` になるケースは普通にあると思うのですが、そこは問題ないでしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。そうですか、、このクラスを描画すれば、myPickerがnilになることはないとおもっていたのですが、そのへんの理解があいまいかもしれないです。fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb) 　となって開かずにエラーでシャットダウンしてしまいます。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> nibファイルを複数作成しており、そのTableViewのrowに応じて　nibファイルをレンダリングしようとしております。
>   nibファイルには、cellにTextFieldクラスの物や、　UIPickerViewクラスのもの、　ボタンしかないものの３種類です。
>
> 以下のUITableViewCellを継承したCustomAddTrainingクラスは、複数のnibファイルに使用できるように、一つのファイルにまとめてあります。

この場合、nib ファイルによっては「接続していない outlet 」があると思うのですが、`CustomAddTraining` クラスがインスタンス化されたとき、それらはそのまま `nil` になります。

ですので、コード中で接続されていない可能性のある outlet にアクセスするときは、`nil` である場合を想定しておく必要があります。

あとは通常 Swift でオプショナルな値を扱う方法で書き直せばいいのですが、この場合は outlet の型が `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional` になっているのがそもそも実状に合っていないので、`Optional` に変更してしまうのがいいのではないかなと思います：

```
@IBOutlet weak var done: UIButton?
@IBOutlet weak var decideButton: UIButton?
@IBOutlet weak var myTextField: UITextField?

@IBOutlet weak var myPicker: UIPickerView?
```

変更すると、コンパイラが修正の必要な箇所を指摘してくれると思います。

Comment: できました！！！　
ppm様！！！師匠！！！　ありがとうございます！！
optionalについての理解不足でした、
もう一つ教えていただけたらと思うのですが、nibファイルを複数作成した場合には、＞nib ファイルによっては「接続されていない outlet 」が出てくると思う　というのは何故でしょうか？　呼び出される順番に起因するものですか？

Comment: コメントをいただいた部分をちょっと編集してみました。

例えば「ボタンしかない nib ファイル」では、 @YOSUKE さまは `myTextField ` や `myPicker` には何も接続していないのではないでしょうか？

その nib ファイルが読み込まれた時に行われる処理はだいたい次のようなもので、呼び出し順のような難しい原因ではなく、単純に何も設定されないので、`myTextField` や `myPicker` は `nil` になります：

`let cell = CustomAddTraining(); cell.done = <nib 上でレイアウトしたボタン>; cell.decideButton = <nib 上でレイアウトしたボタン>`

Comment: なるほど、このnibファイルを複数集めたカスタムクラスをインスタンス化させるときには、すべて使用しているわけではない（使用してないものはnilになる）からこそ、nilになる可能性がないImplicitlyUnwrappedOptionalを使用しているのは実情に合っていないということですね！！ ありがとうございました、助かりました！！